# Problem with sending request in Playwright

Tags: typescript, automated-tests, playwright, playwright-test

I'm trying to do request but without success.

```
async getToken() {
    let response;
    const browser = await chromium.launch();
    const context = await browser.newContext(
      {
        proxy: {
          server: 'https://.org/',
        },
      },
    );

    try {
      response = await context.request.post(
        endpoint,
        {
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          },
          form: {
            username: usernameValue,
            password: passwordValue,
            grant_type: 'password',
            client_id: 'admin-cli',
          },
        });
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(error);
    } finally {
      if (browser) {
        await browser.close();
      }
    }

    const responseData = await response.json() as LoginResponseBody;
    this.token = responseData.access_token;
    await browser.close();
}
```

```
Error message: 
Error while obtaining token: Error: Error: apiRequestContext.post: Socket is closed
=========================== logs ===========================
→ POST myEndpoint
  user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/117.0.5938.62 Safari/537.36
  accept: */*
  accept-encoding: gzip,deflate,br
  Authorization: Basic
  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  content-length: 98
← 400 Bad Request
  server: awselb/2.0
  date: Wed, 13 Dec 2023 13:26:20 GMT
  content-type: text/html
  content-length: 122
  connection: close
```

It's strange because in Postman I do same request with status 200

in headers I'm adding:

```
  'Authorization': 'Basic',
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
```

and in body (x-www-form-urlencoded):

```
username: usernameValue,
password: passwordValue,
grant_type: 'password',
client_id: 'admin-cli',
```

I think it's a problem of proxy (Postman is using system proxy), so I tried to add proxy to my code as you can see above. Without it I'm getting a 503 error.